# Parallel background tasks on single worker dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, background-process, delayed-job, resque

We've got a Rails app where certain requests trigger long-running tasks on a worker dyno with delayed_job, while the front-end polls until it receives a result.

Our traffic is small but growing, and the tasks generally take only a few seconds to complete, but *can* take up to a minute. Right now a single web and worker dyno each should be sufficient to handle our load.

The problem is, the delayed_job queue won't process jobs in parallel, so a longer task ends up holding up the tasks behind it.

What we're looking for is something like Unicorn for the backend, where a single worker dyno can process multiple tasks concurrently. And since it's Rails, we're looking for something multi-process, not multi-threaded.

(We tried creating multiple worker entries in our procfile- This worked on the local dev box, but not on Heroku)

**Procfile:**

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
# Multiple workers defined here doesn't translate into multiple processes on single worker dyno:
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

This Heroku article proposes using the [resque-pool gem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-resque-pool) as a solution. Is that the only solution, or can delayed_job be used for parallel background jobs as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @radiospiel's [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764369/165673), you can use foreman to start multiple processes.

1) Add foreman to your Gemfile

2) Create two files:

**Procfile:**

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.workers
```

**Procfile.workers:**

```
dj_worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
dj_worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
dj_worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

I just deployed this to Heroku, works great.

Comment: @quantumpotato - Not sure what you mean. Unicorn manages its own worker processes, which you configure in `config/unicorn.rb`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Run lengthy (several seconds+) tasks in the background without stalling the request, but only scale up dynamically to handle the queued jobs

Comment: @quantumpotato - maybe start a new question, I'm still not clear on what you're after

Comment: A worker process can handle web requests or do background tasks, yes?

Comment: @quantumpotato I don't think you can use worker dynos for web requests. You'll need more web dynos for that.